# How do I write array of word count to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have written a code that counts all of word of text and number of occurrence, the output is:

```
doctype 1
html 3
dir 1
rtl 5
lang 1
head 17
```

I want to write this output to a csv file in the format word and count comma separated.

```
# Open the file in read mode 
text = open("output.txt", "r") 

# Create an empty dictionary 
d = dict() 

# Loop through each line of the file 
for line in text: 
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character 
    line = line.strip() 

    # Convert the characters in line to  
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch 
    line = line.lower() 

    # Split the line into words 
    words = line.split(" ") 

    # Iterate over each word in line 
    for word in words: 
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary 
        if word in d: 
            # Increment count of word by 1 
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else: 
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1 
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary 

for key in list(d.keys()): 
    print ( key, ":", d[key])
```

Comment: Use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: And also, you could try the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open('my_csv_file.csv','w') as writer:
    for key, val in d.items():
        writer.write("{},{}\n".format(key,val)
```

This will write the dictionary to an outfile in a "key,val" format